# Importing a local swift module

Tags: swift, module, package

Swift newbie here, using swift 3 on Linux with the package manager.

I have a package Regulate, executable, and a sibling package Utils, intended to be a library. Utils/Sources has a TextReader.swift file, with class TextReader and its init function both public. The Utils directory is a git repo, described in Regulate/Package.swift:

```
dependencies: [.Package(url: "../Utils", "1.0.0")]
```

I've tried 3 ways to instantiate a TextReader object in the Regulate program and gotten 3 error messages:

```
import Utils
...
let reader = TextReader(filename: name)
```

error: use of unresolved identifier 'TextReader'

```
import Utils
...
let reader = Utils.TextReader(filename: name)
```

error: module 'Utils' has no member named 'TextReader'

```
import class Utils.TextReader
```

error: no such decl in module

It looks like the library module needs some additional structure to declare its exports, perhaps.

What do I need to do here? Thanks!

Comment: What does `Utils/Package.swift` look like? Can you successfully run `swift build` on `Utils` standalone, and on `Regulate` with the `Utils` dependency in `Package.swift` but no code to import the `TextReader`?

Comment: Utils/Package.swift has only the name: "Utils" line, and it appears to build standalone - no complaints, and reasonable looking output in .build. Also, Regulate builds successfully with the Utils dependency, and import Utils in the code, but no reference to TextReader.

Comment: Gotcha. When you build `Regulate`, you see a line that it is cloning `Utils`, and you see the `Utils` source code with your `Regulate/Packages` subdirectory? Also, if you didn't use `swift package init` to get started with `Utils`, it might be worth backing it up , trying a fresh package initialization, and copying back the code you need into the generated package structure.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! This looks like a name conflict.

When I use Utils2 instead of Utils, it works fine. With Utils it cloned and built the other module, but apparently went to some system module instead when I referenced it.